# Upgrade 1.9.1 Google Analytics not tracking anymore

Tags: magento-1.9, google-analytics

Since upgrading from **Magento CE 1.7.0.2** to **1.9.1** its not showing any visitors. Google is activated and I use the **Fooman extension**.

Any ideas why its not tracking visitors?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you switch to the responsive theme?

Comment: How do you mean. The custom Theme stayed the same. Just magento got upgraded

Comment: is the google analytics code included in the frontend?

Comment: Yes the code is in the Source on the frobtend

Answer (score 2):

In version **1.9.1**, Magento added an admin configuration setting for setting different Google Analytics code types. You can see this setting by going to:

> **Admin > Configuration > Sales > Google API > Google Analytics > Type**

There should be two options here "Universal Analytics" and "Google Analytics". Older versions of Magento did not have this setting and would always default to Universal Analytics code. After upgrading to 1.9.1, I believe Magento now automatically defaults to Google Analytics code instead. This caused issues for me with `Uncaught ReferenceError: ga is not defined` errors showing up in the console on pages.

I resolved it by switching the config setting, **Type**, back to **Universal Analtyics** and my errors went away and my tracking came back.

You can see the conditional for the two different GA code types and what the code looks like in:

> app\design\frontend\base\default\template\googleanalytics\ga.phtml

Answer (score 1):

Magento 1.9.1 uses universal analytics.  You need to enable universal analytics on google if you haven't already.

Probably the fooman extension is outdated.  Old version didnt support UA.  Now it does. Update extension and make sure UA is enabled on google.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/google-analytics-by-fooman.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I use universal and when updating to 1.9.1 I updated all extensions. But I'll check again

Comment: Also try using tag assistant chrome extension

Answer (score 0):

+1 on Ladle3000, a good idea also is to checkout Blue Acorn's Univeral analytics extension which enables your site voor enhanced e-commerce.
This will give your much more insight in the performance and potential problems in your store.

More info on Enhanced e-commerce: http://analytics.blogspot.nl/2014/05/better-data-better-decisions-enhanced.html

and the Blue Acron http://www.blueacorn.com/magento-blog/google-universal-analytics-enhanced-ecommerce-magento/